# Polar angle of a given point

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

How to find out polar angle of a given point $A(x_1,y_1)$  relative to another point $B(x_2,y_2)$  in a 2D space?

Answer (score 3):

$\tan^{-1}{y_2-y_1\over x_2-x_1}$